# Germany: how to upgrade A1 licence issued elsewhere to full A after moving to Germany?

Tags: germany, driving-license

I have an A1 category licence issued in Poland in 2005, am 26 and moving to Germany for a year shortly. How do I upgrade my licence to full A once I am German resident (I assume temporary residence is enough for a year)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by “temporary residence is enough for a year”, what will be your status?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, in the EU, everything related to driving licenses should be dealt with by your state of residence. So once you become a German resident, you are supposed to get your license in Germany following the local rules.

Based on a quick websearch (e.g. [this site](http://www.zweiradfuehrerschein.de/)) it seems there are two ways to obtain an unrestricted A license in Germany:

- The “direct way”: Taking a course and a theoretical and practical exam (you can do this because you are older than 26).
- Upgrade from A2 license: Taking a practical exam after holding the A2 license for two years.

The A2 license can itself be obtained through a practical exam if you have your A1 license since more than two years.